# The splitting of the moon: any metaphoric explanation?

Tags: quran, moon, surat-al-qamar

Verse 1 of Surah Al-Qamar very clearly references the story of the moon being split. Mostly I hear the explanation that includes our prophet (PBUH) and the Quraish witnesses.

However, I am also convinced that a splitting of the moon is scientifically impossible. Is it possible that this verse has a deeper meaning? Is it perhaps written to illustrate that even a miracle of such scale would not convince a person who is a disbeliever at heart? 
Or perhaps the word splitting would not necessarily mean a very large part of the moon was split from it, or that both parts of the moon weren't joined back together after the miracle?

I ask this question because I am a recent convert, but was raised as a sceptical atheist who still has a strong desire to see logic and faith joined together!

Comment: If it was scientifically possible would it even be a miracle or  would it be a natural phenomenon? The splitting of the sea by Moses (AS) was also not scientifically possible nor was his staff turning into a snake. The point of miracles is that they are unexplainable, "magical," defying-the-laws-of-the-universe-type events.

Comment: There are other interpretations of it, including one that it is a prophecy about the future, i.e. the moon *will* split. However it being literal and the miracle already having occurred in Makkah is supported by authentic reports.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! By metaphoric explanation, I meant to seek the intent behind this verse rather than to see it as something that did not take place. When I read the sura, the emphasis on the reaction of the Quraish seemed to me as if there is a moral lesson to be grasped and that this is not just a casual mention of a miracle. 
I apologise thoroughly if I came across as someone who rejects this verse and does not believe in miracles. It was not the point of this question to contest the historical event, rather to fully understand it.

Answer (score -3):

The splitting of the moon was not a physical thing because it is not scientifically possible. Allah is not so weak to break His own laws of nature to prove anything to man.

The above 2 examples of Moses are incorrect. The sea didn't not split in half. That is impossible. All that happened is that the tide went low enough for them to walk across. You see the tide of water going up and down every day at the beach. This is scientific proof. Allah has made religion easy but misinterpretation by man has created confusion.